# JSONException - No value for success - JsonParser - Android

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I have a JsonParser that works well. I can pass data to PHP/MySQL and I can retrieve data to. The problem is at some Android app activities that I have more than one AsyncTasks.

An example:

1. When I open MainActivity it executes an Async that check if user is or not subscribed to a radio. It's working well.
2. In this activity, I can subscribe or unsubscribe. When I execute Subcribe or Unsubscribe Async's the problem begins.
3. When I click subscribe (for example), it send user data to php and register it in MySQL. It works.
4. php send a Json response (success = 0 or 1). It works to.
5. Android/Java JsonParser.class pass this response as a JSONObject. It works only for the first Async.

The problem:

I need to get value of success, but when JsonParser receive the second value (Subscribe - first value is checkSubscription), logcat shows me that success don't have a value, but success have a value.

Logcat:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for success
```

Response:

```
11-25 17:22:37.346 22731-22909/com.package.package D/JSON Parser: result: {"subsuccess":0,"message":"Not Subscribed"}
11-25 17:22:37.346 22731-22909/com.package.package D/JSON Parser: {"success":1,"message":"Subscribed."}
```

> Second line, value 1 of tag success is what I need.

JsonParser.class:

```
package com.package.package;

import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class JsonParser {

    String charset = "UTF-8";
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    DataOutputStream wr;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    URL urlObj;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    StringBuilder sbParams;
    String paramsString;
    String json = "";

    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      HashMap<String, String> params) {

        sbParams = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        for (String key : params.keySet()) {
            try {
                if (i != 0) {
                    sbParams.append("&");
                }
                sbParams.append(key).append("=")
                        .append(URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key), charset));

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }

        if (method.equals("POST")) {
            // request method is POST
            try {


                urlObj = new URL(url);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                //request.setEntity(new BufferingRepresentation(request.getEntity());

                conn.connect();

                paramsString = sbParams.toString();

                wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(paramsString);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (method.equals("GET")) {
            // request method is GET

            if (sbParams.length() != 0) {
                url += "?" + sbParams.toString();
            }

            try {
                urlObj = new URL(url);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(false);

                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                conn.connect();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        try {
            //Receive the response from the server
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line + "\n");
            }
            json = result.toString();

            Log.d("JSON Parser", "result: " + result.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        conn.disconnect();

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            Log.d("JSON Parser Obj", jObj.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON Object
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

AsyncTask:

```
class checkSubscription extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    int success = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DetailsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String url_check = meuhelper.ip + meuhelper.url_check_subscription;

        // Building Parameters
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("id", args[0]);
        params.put("nome", args[1]);
        params.put("email", args[2]);

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_check,
                "POST", params);

        try {

            final int subscription = json.getInt(TAG_SUBSCRIPTION);

            String strSuccess = Integer.toString(subscription);
            Log.e("Check - ok", strSuccess);

            if (subscription == 1) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //subUnsub();
                        btnSub.setText(R.string.btnUnsubscribe);
                        Log.d("SUBSCRIPTION =====>", "1");
                    }
                });
            } else if (subscription == 0){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //subUnsub();
                        btnSub.setText(R.string.btnSubscribe);
                        Log.d("SUBSCRIPTION =====>", "0");
                    }
                });
            }
        }  catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

class registrarAssinatura extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    int regSuccess = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DetailsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading");
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        String url_create = meuhelper.ip + meuhelper.url_create_subscription;

        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("email", args[0]);
        params.put("nome", args[1]);

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create,
                "POST", params);




        if (json != null) {
            try {
                regSuccess = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                String x = json.getJSONObject(TAG_SUCCESS).get(TAG_SUCCESS).toString();
                Log.d("WHAT", x);
                message = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                Log.d("Success", message);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
        super.onPostExecute(json);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();

        if (regSuccess == 1) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //subUnsub();
                    Log.d("REGISTRAR =====>", "REGISTRADO");
                }
            });
        } else if (regSuccess == 0) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //subUnsub();
                    Log.d("FAIL TO REGISTER =====>", "REGISTRADO");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

class cancelarAssinatura extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DetailsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading");
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String url_cancel = meuhelper.ip + meuhelper.url_cancel_subscription;

        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("email", args[0]);
        params.put("nome", args[1]);

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_cancel,
                "POST", params);

        try {

            int cancelSuccess = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            String strSuccess = Integer.toString(cancelSuccess);
            Log.e("Cancel - ok", strSuccess);

            if (cancelSuccess == 1) {
                Log.e("Cancel - feito", strSuccess);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //subUnsub();
                    }
                });
            } else if (cancelSuccess == 0){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //subUnsub();
                    }
                });
                Log.e("Cancel - deu ruim", strSuccess);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Above are 3 AsyncTask at same Activity. All of them work well, I just can't get success response.

```
11-25 18:08:45.884 31070-31218/com.podchest.podchest D/JSON Parser: result: {"subsuccess":0,"message":"Not Subscribed"}
11-25 18:08:45.884 31070-31218/com.podchest.podchest D/JSON Parser: {"success":1,"message":"Subscribed."}
11-25 18:08:45.884 31070-31218/com.podchest.podchest D/JSON Parser Obj: {"message":"Not Subscribed","subsuccess":0}
11-25 18:08:45.884 31070-31218/com.podchest.podchest D/JSON TO STRING: {"message":"Not Subscribed","subsuccess":0}
```

Above JDev test. So, I'm not receiving second response from JsonParser?

I'm all the day trying to fix it. I have read other posts on Stack, no one helped me.
I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Post the entire code of your AsyncTask.

Comment: in what line of code do you print `11-25 17:22:37.346 22731-22909/com.package.package D/JSON Parser: {"success":1,"message":"Subscribed."}` ?

Comment: JsonParser.class: `Log.d("JSON Parser", "result: " + result.toString());`

Comment: No that's not the corresponding line. The line I'm asking for has no "result" string in the Logcat output.

Comment: It is. I'm using a break line: `result.append(line + "\n");` So, line 1 and 2 are only one.

Comment: Before you call `regSuccess = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);` , try to log `json.toString()` to the console & show me what does it print.

Comment: So it turned out that you weren't receiving the data you wanted.

Comment: Yep. But logcat shows it. How can I get it?

Comment: Try `json.getJSONObject(0).get("subsuccess")` instead of `json.getJSONObject(TAG_SUCCESS).get(TAG_SUCCESS)`

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Your test openned my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is the JSONParser [from my blog](http://danielnugent.blogspot.com/2015/06/updated-jsonparser-with.html).

Recently someone mentioned that they had to make one small change to get it to work with multiple requests, I've been meaning to update my blog with the change.

The change is to initialize the `result` StringBuilder every time a request is made.

Here is the full class with the modified code:

```
public class JsonParser {

    String charset = "UTF-8";
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    DataOutputStream wr;
    //StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder result; //modified - don't initialize here
    URL urlObj;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    StringBuilder sbParams;
    String paramsString;
    String json = "";

    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      HashMap<String, String> params) {

        sbParams = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        for (String key : params.keySet()) {
            try {
                if (i != 0) {
                    sbParams.append("&");
                }
                sbParams.append(key).append("=")
                        .append(URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key), charset));

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }

        if (method.equals("POST")) {
            // request method is POST
            try {


                urlObj = new URL(url);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                //request.setEntity(new BufferingRepresentation(request.getEntity());

                conn.connect();

                paramsString = sbParams.toString();

                wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(paramsString);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (method.equals("GET")) {
            // request method is GET

            if (sbParams.length() != 0) {
                url += "?" + sbParams.toString();
            }

            try {
                urlObj = new URL(url);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(false);

                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                conn.connect();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        try {
            //Receive the response from the server
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            String line;
            result = new StringBuilder(); //added
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line + "\n");
            }
            json = result.toString();

            Log.d("JSON Parser", "result: " + result.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        conn.disconnect();

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            Log.d("JSON Parser Obj", jObj.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON Object
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

Comment: subsuccess is not the problem, I have tested it. The initialization of StringBuilder solved the problem. Thank you so much for the working class, for this answer and thank the person who did this small change. I can use this class, sure?

Comment: @Alan Nice, I'll modify the answer.  Sorry for the bug in the original code!  Yep, you can use it, glad it's working for you!